# How to make a UNION (or JOIN) query between two tables where 1st has higher priority without duplicates?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make a performant UNION (or JOIN) query between two tables:

```
tableA
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  7 |
+----+
```

```
tableB
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  9 |
+----+
```

Where it should produce the following output:

```
outputTable
+----+-----------+
| id | fromTable |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | TableA    |
|  2 | TableA    |
|  7 | TableA    |
|  9 | TableB    |
+----+-----------+
```

I want to reproduce the behavior of select tableA and then union (or join) the rows that aren't on tableA or by another words union tableA and tableB with `fromTable` priority on tableA. What's the best way to accomplish this **(performance wise)**?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a full join. For example:

```
select
  coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id, 
  case when a.id is null then 'TableB' else 'TableA' end as from_table
from a
full join b on a.id = b.id
```

Result:

```
id  from_table
--- ----------
1   TableA
2   TableA
7   TableA
9   TableB
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4e56548d0de2c93eb840da3b14f11360).

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that:

```
select id, 'tableA'
from tableA
union all
select id, 'tableB'
from tableB
where tableB.id not in (select id from tableA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ids of `tableB` that don't exist in `tableA` with `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT id FROM tableB
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM tableA
```

and your final query would be:

```
SELECT id, 'tableA' fromTable FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'tableB'
FROM (
  SELECT id FROM tableB
  EXCEPT
  SELECT id FROM tableA
) t
ORDER BY id;
```

or:

```
SELECT id, 'tableB' fromTable FROM tableB
EXCEPT
SELECT id, 'tableB' FROM tableA
UNION 
SELECT id, 'tableA' FROM tableA
ORDER BY id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dadd2d1a3370e4016d3292beef45b2da).